# Routes.php not working just being completely bypassed

Tags: php, laravel-5, routes

So I have been working on Laravel projects with no issues at my new job, however I decided it was time to get it up and running on my system at home which for purposes of this question is running MS Windows 10. I managed to get it all set up correctly, however upon trying to get the test app working just to make sure everything was correctly configured, I am unable to get passed the laravel welcome (welcome.blade.php) despite having the Routes.php file in place.

The clean project was git cloned directly from laravel/laravel and I had no issues with this working on my work computer when I very first started learning Laravel. I'm not getting any errors, the routes are simply not working!

Btw I had to create the Routes.php file manually for some reason, even though I created my migrations and did:

```
artisan migrate
```

The views directory I created called 'testview' is being completely ignored in the routes file when calling:

```
Route::get('/', 'TestController@index');
```

Controller code:

```
Return view('testview.index');
```

That is within the public function index() just for those who try to be smart and say "oh but you didn't have it contained within a method".

Please could someone help and tell me where I'm going wrong??

Answer (score 0):

It seems that for some reason the version of laravel on GIT is out of date as I peformed a different command line action using Composer and that installed the latest version. So in closing I've sorted this out myself, thanks.